# Hacer que un enlace <a> ocupe sólo su espacio

Tags: css

Estoy tratando de crear el diseño de la pagina de WhatsApp, para practicar un poco, pero tengo algunos problemas. Cuando paso el puntero sobre los *links* no ocupa solo el espacio de la palabra, sino que ocupa todo el div, he intentado con `display:inline-block` y sigue igual, les dejo el codigo abajo.

¿Podrían ayudarme?, gracias

```css
:root{
    --colorBarra: #128c7e;
    --colorA1: #D8E8EA;
    --colorA2: #E7F0E4;
    --negro: #000000;
    --blanco: #ffffff;
    --gris: #5E5E5E;
    --boton : #77d7c8;

    --fuenteBarra: 'Roboto', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;

}

html{
    box-sizing: border-box; /** Para hacer que el border, el padding, etc, no afecte el ancho de nuestros elementos**/
    font-size: 62.5%; /** Para que 1rem = 10px**/ 
}

*, *:before, *:after{
    box-sizing: inherit;

}

body{
    font-family: var(--fuenteBarra);
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    line-height: 2.3rem;
}

img{
    max-width: 100%;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

.contenedor{
    max-width: 120rem;
    width: 85%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.contenedor2{
    max-width: 120rem;
    width: 65%;
    margin: 0 auto;

}

.centrador-texto{
    text-align: center;
}

/** Barra Navegacion**/


.background-nav{
    background-color: var(--colorBarra);
}

.logo-imagen__texto{
    color: var(--blanco);
    font-family: var(--fuenteBarra);
    font-size: 2.4rem;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.barra-nav__enlaces{
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 2.5rem;
    color: var(--blanco);
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    font-family: var(--fuenteBarra);
}

.barra-nav__enlaces:first-of-type{
    margin-top: 2rem;
}

@media (min-width: 769px) {
    .nav{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        padding: .5rem 0;
    }
    .barra-nav__enlaces{
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    .logo-imagen{
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .logo-imagen__texto{
        margin-left: 1rem;
    }

    .barra-nav{
        display: flex;
    }
    .barra-nav__enlaces{
        margin-right: 3rem;
    }
    .barra-nav__enlaces:last-of-type{
        margin-right: 0;
    }
    .barra-nav__enlaces:first-of-type{
        margin-top: 0;
    }

}

/** Contenido debajo del nav**/
.c-principal{
    margin-top: 5rem;
    margin-bottom: 5rem;
}

.c-izquierda__titulos{
    font-size: 3.5rem;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 1rem;

}

.c-izquierda__titulos:first-of-type{
    line-height: 4rem;
}

.c-izquierda__contenido{
    text-align: left;

}

.c-izquierda__gris{
    text-align: left;
    color: var(--gris);
    margin-bottom: 4rem;

}

.dispositivos{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}

.dispositivos__enlaces{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding-bottom: 2rem;
}

.dispositivos__nombre{
    padding: 0 .3rem;
    color: var(--colorBarra);
}

.dispositivos__nombre:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
}

@media (min-width: 769px) {
    .c-principal{
        display: grid;  
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
        column-gap: 5rem;
    }
    
    .c-izquierda{
        padding: 10rem 0;
    }
}

/** Seccion Secundaria **/

.s-izquierda{
    background-color: var(--colorA1);
    padding: 5rem;
}

.s-izquierda__contenido,
.s-derecha__contenido{
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    line-height: 2.6rem;
}

.s-izquierda__titulo,
.s-derecha__titulo{
    font-size: 3rem;
    line-height: 4rem;
}

.s-izquierda__contenido:last-of-type{
    margin-bottom: 7rem;
}

.s-derecha{
    background-color: var(--colorA2);
    padding: 5rem;
}

.s-derecha__encabezado{
    color: #5E5E5E;
    letter-spacing: .2rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 1.8rem;
}

.s-izquierda img{
    max-width: 80%;
}

.s-izquierda__enlace{
    color: #39b3ed;
}

.s-derecha img{
    margin-bottom: 7rem;
}

@media (min-width: 769px) {
    .c-secundario{
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
        column-gap: 5rem;
    }
    
}

/** Boton **/
.boton{
    margin: 4rem;
}

.boton .boton-ex{
    border: 2px solid var(--boton);
    border-radius: 50rem;
    padding: 1.5rem 4rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: var(--colorBarra);
}

/** Menu de abajo**/

.fondo-menu{
    background-color: #273443;
    padding: 2.5rem 0;
}

.menus p{
    color: var(--blanco);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: .2rem;
}

.menus{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>WhatsApp</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="background-nav">
            <div class="nav contenedor centrador-texto">

                <a href="#" class="logo-imagen">
                    <img src="img/wsp_logo.png" alt="Imagen logo" class="logo-imagen__logo">
                    <p class="logo-imagen__texto">WhatsApp</p>
                </a>

                <nav class="barra-nav">
                    <a href="#" class="barra-nav__enlaces">WHATSAPP WEB</a>
                    <a href="#" class="barra-nav__enlaces">FUNCIONES</a>
                    <a href="#" class="barra-nav__enlaces">DESCARGAR</a>
                    <a href="#" class="barra-nav__enlaces">SEGURIDAD</a>
                    <a href="#" class="barra-nav__enlaces">CENTRO DE AYUDA</a>
                </nav>
            </div> <!--.nav-->

        </div>
    </header>

    <main class="contenedor2 centrador-texto">
        <div class="c-principal">

            <div class="c-izquierda">
                <p class="c-izquierda__titulos">Mensajería confiable,</p>
                <p class="c-izquierda__titulos">Simple,</p>
                <p class="c-izquierda__titulos">Segura</p>

                <p class="c-izquierda__contenido">
                    Con WhatsApp, la mensajería y las llamadas son rápidas, simples, seguras y gratuitas*, disponibles en teléfonos alrededor del mundo.
                </p>
                <p class="c-izquierda__gris">
                    * Puede haber cargos adicionales por el uso del servicio de datos. Contacta a tu operador de telefonía móvil para más información.
                </p>

                <ul class="dispositivos">
                    <li class="dispositivos__wsp">
                        <a href="#" class="dispositivos__enlaces">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px"
                                width="24" height="24"
                                viewBox="0 0 172 172"
                                style=" fill:#000000;"><g fill="none" fill-rule="nonzero" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="" stroke-dashoffset="0" font-family="none" font-weight="none" font-size="none" text-anchor="none" style="mix-blend-mode: normal"><path d="M0,172v-172h172v172z" fill="none"></path><g id="original-icon" fill="#128c7e"><path d="M53.75,7.16667c-0.91733,0 -1.83478,0.35105 -2.53353,1.0498c-1.3975,1.3975 -1.3975,3.66956 0,5.06706l9.39225,9.39225c-10.66343,7.82497 -17.60872,20.41563 -17.60872,34.65755h86c0,-14.24192 -6.9453,-26.83258 -17.60872,-34.65755l9.39225,-9.39225c1.3975,-1.40467 1.3975,-3.66239 0,-5.06706c-1.3975,-1.3975 -3.66956,-1.3975 -5.06706,0l-10.62402,10.62402c-5.75803,-2.86198 -12.22542,-4.50716 -19.09244,-4.50716c-6.86703,0 -13.33441,1.64518 -19.09245,4.50716l-10.62402,-10.62402c-0.69875,-0.69875 -1.6162,-1.0498 -2.53353,-1.0498zM64.5,35.83333h7.16667v7.16667h-7.16667zM100.33333,35.83333h7.16667v7.16667h-7.16667zM28.66667,64.5c-3.956,0 -7.16667,3.21067 -7.16667,7.16667v43c0,3.956 3.21067,7.16667 7.16667,7.16667c3.956,0 7.16667,-3.21067 7.16667,-7.16667v-43c0,-3.956 -3.21067,-7.16667 -7.16667,-7.16667zM43,64.5v57.33333c0,3.956 3.21067,7.16667 7.16667,7.16667h7.16667v25.08333c0,5.934 4.816,10.75 10.75,10.75c5.934,0 10.75,-4.816 10.75,-10.75v-25.08333h14.33333v25.08333c0,5.934 4.816,10.75 10.75,10.75c5.934,0 10.75,-4.816 10.75,-10.75v-25.08333h7.16667c3.956,0 7.16667,-3.21067 7.16667,-7.16667v-57.33333zM143.33333,64.5c-3.956,0 -7.16667,3.21067 -7.16667,7.16667v43c0,3.956 3.21067,7.16667 7.16667,7.16667c3.956,0 7.16667,-3.21067 7.16667,-7.16667v-43c0,-3.956 -3.21067,-7.16667 -7.16667,-7.16667z"></path></g></g>
                            </svg>
                            <span class="dispositivos__nombre">Android</span>
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px"
                                width="30" height="30"
                                viewBox="0 0 172 172"
                                style=" fill:#000000;"><g fill="none" fill-rule="nonzero" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="" stroke-dashoffset="0" font-family="none" font-weight="none" font-size="none" text-anchor="none" style="mix-blend-mode: normal"><path d="M0,172v-172h172v172z" fill="none"></path><g fill="#128c7e"><path d="M68.8,154.8h-11.46667c-2.21307,0 -4.2312,-1.27853 -5.18293,-3.27947c-0.95173,-2.00093 -0.65933,-4.3688 0.74533,-6.0888l48.63013,-59.43173l-48.63013,-59.43747c-1.40467,-1.71427 -1.69133,-4.08213 -0.74533,-6.0888c0.946,-2.00667 2.96987,-3.27373 5.18293,-3.27373h11.46667c1.72,0 3.34827,0.774 4.4376,2.10413l51.6,63.06667c1.72573,2.1156 1.72573,5.14853 0,7.26413l-51.6,63.06667c-1.08933,1.3244 -2.7176,2.0984 -4.4376,2.0984z"></path></g></g>
                            </svg>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="dispositivos__enlaces">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px"
                            width="24" height="24"
                            viewBox="0 0 172 172"
                            style=" fill:#000000;"><g fill="none" fill-rule="nonzero" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="" stroke-dashoffset="0" font-family="none" font-weight="none" font-size="none" text-anchor="none" style="mix-blend-mode: normal"><path d="M0,172v-172h172v172z" fill="none"></path><g fill="#128c7e"><path d="M113.9808,7.72656c-0.43672,-0.06719 -0.93223,-0.0252 -1.46973,0.15397c-7.16667,1.43333 -15.0416,5.73333 -20.05827,10.75c-4.3,4.3 -7.88054,11.46667 -7.88054,17.91667c0,1.43333 1.42214,2.86947 2.85547,2.86947c7.88333,-0.71667 15.76946,-5.01947 20.78613,-10.03613c4.3,-5.73333 7.88054,-12.18053 7.88054,-18.63053c0,-1.6125 -0.80345,-2.82188 -2.11361,-3.02344zM116.0944,38.7028c-12.9,0 -18.62493,7.88053 -27.22493,7.88053c-9.31667,0 -17.91667,-7.16667 -28.66667,-7.16667c-15.05,0 -37.98893,14.33053 -37.98893,47.2972c-0.71667,30.1 26.51947,63.78614 42.28613,63.78614c9.31667,0 11.46947,-5.73893 24.36947,-5.73893c12.9,0 15.76667,5.73893 25.08333,5.73893c10.75,0 18.63333,-11.46947 25.08333,-20.78614c2.86667,-5.01667 5.01667,-7.87773 7.16667,-12.17773c1.43333,-2.86667 -0.0028,-5.73333 -2.86947,-7.16667c-18.63333,-9.31667 -22.21107,-39.41667 -1.42774,-50.16667c3.58333,-2.15 4.2944,-6.4584 1.42774,-8.6084c-7.88333,-7.16667 -19.3556,-12.8916 -27.23893,-12.8916z"></path></g></g>
                            </svg>
                            <span class="dispositivos__nombre">iPhone</span>
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px"
                                width="30" height="30"
                                viewBox="0 0 172 172"
                                style=" fill:#000000;"><g fill="none" fill-rule="nonzero" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="" stroke-dashoffset="0" font-family="none" font-weight="none" font-size="none" text-anchor="none" style="mix-blend-mode: normal"><path d="M0,172v-172h172v172z" fill="none"></path><g fill="#128c7e"><path d="M68.8,154.8h-11.46667c-2.21307,0 -4.2312,-1.27853 -5.18293,-3.27947c-0.95173,-2.00093 -0.65933,-4.3688 0.74533,-6.0888l48.63013,-59.43173l-48.63013,-59.43747c-1.40467,-1.71427 -1.69133,-4.08213 -0.74533,-6.0888c0.946,-2.00667 2.96987,-3.27373 5.18293,-3.27373h11.46667c1.72,0 3.34827,0.774 4.4376,2.10413l51.6,63.06667c1.72573,2.1156 1.72573,5.14853 0,7.26413l-51.6,63.06667c-1.08933,1.3244 -2.7176,2.0984 -4.4376,2.0984z"></path></g></g>
                            </svg>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="dispositivos__enlaces">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px"
                            width="30" height="30"
                            viewBox="0 0 172 172"
                            style=" fill:#000000;"><g fill="none" fill-rule="nonzero" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="" stroke-dashoffset="0" font-family="none" font-weight="none" font-size="none" text-anchor="none" style="mix-blend-mode: normal"><path d="M0,172v-172h172v172z" fill="none"></path><g fill="#128c7e"><path d="M158.93947,131.86667c0.98613,-1.69133 1.59387,-3.63493 1.59387,-5.73333v-86c0,-6.32387 -5.1428,-11.46667 -11.46667,-11.46667h-126.13333c-6.32387,0 -11.46667,5.1428 -11.46667,11.46667v86c0,2.0984 0.60773,4.042 1.59387,5.73333h-13.06053v5.73333c0,6.33533 5.13133,11.46667 11.46667,11.46667h149.06667c6.33533,0 11.46667,-5.13133 11.46667,-11.46667v-5.73333zM103.2,126.13333c0,3.1648 -2.56853,5.73333 -5.73333,5.73333h-17.2c-3.1648,0 -5.73333,-2.56853 -5.73333,-5.73333h-51.6v-86h126.13333l0.00573,86z"></path></g></g>
                            </svg>
                                <span class="dispositivos__nombre">Mac o Windows</span>
                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px"
                                width="30" height="30"
                                viewBox="0 0 172 172"
                                style=" fill:#000000;"><g fill="none" fill-rule="nonzero" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="" stroke-dashoffset="0" font-family="none" font-weight="none" font-size="none" text-anchor="none" style="mix-blend-mode: normal"><path d="M0,172v-172h172v172z" fill="none"></path><g fill="#128c7e"><path d="M68.8,154.8h-11.46667c-2.21307,0 -4.2312,-1.27853 -5.18293,-3.27947c-0.95173,-2.00093 -0.65933,-4.3688 0.74533,-6.0888l48.63013,-59.43173l-48.63013,-59.43747c-1.40467,-1.71427 -1.69133,-4.08213 -0.74533,-6.0888c0.946,-2.00667 2.96987,-3.27373 5.18293,-3.27373h11.46667c1.72,0 3.34827,0.774 4.4376,2.10413l51.6,63.06667c1.72573,2.1156 1.72573,5.14853 0,7.26413l-51.6,63.06667c-1.08933,1.3244 -2.7176,2.0984 -4.4376,2.0984z"></path></g></g>
                            </svg>

                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </div>


            <div class="c-derecha">
                <img src="img/celular.png" alt="Imagen derecha">
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </main>

    <section class="c-secundario centrador-texto">
        <div class="s-izquierda">
            <h2 class="s-izquierda__titulo">Aplicación WhatsApp Business</h2>
            <p class="s-izquierda__contenido">
                <a class="s-izquierda__enlace" href="#">WhatsApp Business</a> es una aplicación de descarga gratuita desarrollada especialmente para pequeñas empresas. Crea un catálogo para mostrar tus productos y servicios. Conéctate fácilmente con tus clientes gracias a las herramientas que te permiten automatizar, organizar y responder con rapidez los mensajes.
            </p>

            <p class="s-izquierda__contenido">WhatsApp también puede ser útil para las empresas medianas y grandes, ya que pueden usarlo para brindar asistencia y enviar notificaciones importantes a sus clientes. Obtén más información sobre la API de WhatsApp Business.
            </p>

            <img src="img/celular2.png" alt="Imagen de la seccion secundaria<">
                

        </div>
        <div class="s-derecha">
            <img src="img/celular3.PNG" alt="Imagen de la seccion secundaria (2)">
            <p class="s-derecha__encabezado">
                CIFRADO DE EXTREMO A EXTREMO
            </p>
            <h2 class="s-derecha__titulo">Seguridad automática</h2>
            <p class="s-derecha__contenido">
                Algunos de tus momentos más personales se comparten a través de WhatsApp; es por ello que desarrollamos el cifrado de extremo a extremo en las versiones más recientes de nuestra aplicación. Con el cifrado de extremo a extremo, tus mensajes y llamadas están protegidos para que solo las personas con las que te comunicas los puedan leer o escuchar sin que nadie más, ni siquiera WhatsApp, lo pueda hacer.
            </p>
            
        </div>
    </section>

    <div class="boton centrador-texto">
        <a href="#" class="boton-ex">Explorar Funciones</a>
    </div>

    <section class="menu-abajo">
        <div class="fondo-menu">
            <div class="c-menu contenedor">
                <div class="menus">
                    <p>WhatsApp</p>
                    <a href="#" class="menus__enlaces">Funciones</a>
                    <a href="#" class="menus__enlaces">Seguridad</a>
                    <a href="#" class="menus__enlaces">Descargar</a>
                    <a href="#" class="menus__enlaces">WhatsApp Web</a>
                    <a href="#" class="menus__enlaces">Empresas</a>
                    <a href="#" class="menus__enlaces">Privacidad</a>
                </div>
                <div class="menus">
                    <p>Empresa</p>
                    <a href="#" class="menus__enlaces">Información</a>
                    <a href="#" class="menus__enlaces">Empleo</a>
                    <a href="#" class="menus__enlaces">Nuestra marca</a>
                    <a href="#" class="menus__enlaces">Contáctanos</a>
                    <a href="#" class="menus__enlaces">Blog</a>
                    <a href="#" class="menus__enlaces">Historias de WhatsApp</a>
                </div>
                
                <div class="menus">
                    <p>Descargar</p>
                    <a href="#" class="menus__enlaces">Mac/PC</a>
                    <a href="#" class="menus__enlaces">Android</a>
                    <a href="#" class="menus__enlaces">iPhone</a>
                </div>
                <div class="menus">
                    <p>Ayuda</p>
                    <a href="#" class="menus__enlaces">Centro de ayuda</a>
                    <a href="#" class="menus__enlaces">Twitter</a>
                    <a href="#" class="menus__enlaces">Facebook</a>
                    <a href="#" class="menus__enlaces">Coronavirus</a>
                    <a href="#" class="menus__enlaces">Empresas</a>
                    <a href="#" class="menus__enlaces">Privacidad</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    

    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Una forma en la que puedes lograr lo que intentas es envolver los elementos `<a>` en contenedores tipo `<div>` y ajustar el código [css](/questions/tagged/css) para que use los estilos de color para los elementos `<a>`.

Por ejemplo:

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--blanco);
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  font-family: var(--fuenteBarra);
}
```

Y al contenedor `<div>` le aplicas el siguiente estilo:

```css
.barra-nav__enlaces{
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 2.5rem;
}
```

Por último los enlaces en el código [html](/questions/tagged/html) se verían así:

```html
<div class="barra-nav__enlaces">
    <a href="#">WHATSAPP WEB</a>
</div>
<div class="barra-nav__enlaces">
    <a href="#">FUNCIONES</a>
</div>
...
```

El código funcionando lo puedes ver aquí:

```css
:root{
    --colorBarra: #128c7e;
    --colorA1: #D8E8EA;
    --colorA2: #E7F0E4;
    --negro: #000000;
    --blanco: #ffffff;
    --gris: #5E5E5E;
    --boton : #77d7c8;

    --fuenteBarra: 'Roboto', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;

}

html{
    box-sizing: border-box; /** Para hacer que el border, el padding, etc, no afecte el ancho de nuestros elementos**/
    font-size: 62.5%; /** Para que 1rem = 10px**/ 
}

*, *:before, *:after{
    box-sizing: inherit;

}

body{
    font-family: var(--fuenteBarra);
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    line-height: 2.3rem;
}

img{
    max-width: 100%;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--blanco);
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    font-family: var(--fuenteBarra);
}

.contenedor{
    max-width: 120rem;
    width: 85%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.contenedor2{
    max-width: 120rem;
    width: 65%;
    margin: 0 auto;

}

.centrador-texto{
    text-align: center;
}

/** Barra Navegacion**/


.background-nav{
    background-color: var(--colorBarra);
}

.logo-imagen__texto{
    color: var(--blanco);
    font-family: var(--fuenteBarra);
    font-size: 2.4rem;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.barra-nav__enlaces{
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 2.5rem;
}

.barra-nav__enlaces:first-of-type{
    margin-top: 2rem;
}

/** Contenido debajo del nav**/
.c-principal{
    margin-top: 5rem;
    margin-bottom: 5rem;
}

.c-izquierda__titulos{
    font-size: 3.5rem;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 1rem;

}

.c-izquierda__titulos:first-of-type{
    line-height: 4rem;
}

.c-izquierda__contenido{
    text-align: left;

}

.c-izquierda__gris{
    text-align: left;
    color: var(--gris);
    margin-bottom: 4rem;

}

.dispositivos{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}

.dispositivos__enlaces{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding-bottom: 2rem;
}

.dispositivos__nombre{
    padding: 0 .3rem;
    color: var(--colorBarra);
}

.dispositivos__nombre:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
}

@media (min-width: 769px) {
    .c-principal{
        display: grid;  
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
        column-gap: 5rem;
    }
    
    .c-izquierda{
        padding: 10rem 0;
    }
}

/** Seccion Secundaria **/

.s-izquierda{
    background-color: var(--colorA1);
    padding: 5rem;
}

.s-izquierda__contenido,
.s-derecha__contenido{
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    line-height: 2.6rem;
}

.s-izquierda__titulo,
.s-derecha__titulo{
    font-size: 3rem;
    line-height: 4rem;
}

.s-izquierda__contenido:last-of-type{
    margin-bottom: 7rem;
}

.s-derecha{
    background-color: var(--colorA2);
    padding: 5rem;
}

.s-derecha__encabezado{
    color: #5E5E5E;
    letter-spacing: .2rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 1.8rem;
}

.s-izquierda img{
    max-width: 80%;
}

.s-izquierda__enlace{
    color: #39b3ed;
}

.s-derecha img{
    margin-bottom: 7rem;
}

@media (min-width: 769px) {
    .c-secundario{
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
        column-gap: 5rem;
    }
    
}

/** Boton **/
.boton{
    margin: 4rem;
}

.boton .boton-ex{
    border: 2px solid var(--boton);
    border-radius: 50rem;
    padding: 1.5rem 4rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: var(--colorBarra);
}

/** Menu de abajo**/

.fondo-menu{
    background-color: #273443;
    padding: 2.5rem 0;
}

.menus p{
    color: var(--blanco);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: .2rem;
}

.menus{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>WhatsApp</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="background-nav">
            <div class="nav contenedor centrador-texto">

                <a href="#" class="logo-imagen">
                    <img src="img/wsp_logo.png" alt="Imagen logo" class="logo-imagen__logo">
                    <p class="logo-imagen__texto">WhatsApp</p>
                </a>

                <nav class="barra-nav">
                  <div class="barra-nav__enlaces">
                    <a href="#">WHATSAPP WEB</a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="barra-nav__enlaces">
                    <a href="#">FUNCIONES</a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="barra-nav__enlaces">
                    <a href="#">DESCARGAR</a>
                   </div>
                   <div class="barra-nav__enlaces">
                    <a href="#">SEGURIDAD</a>
                   </div>
                   <div class="barra-nav__enlaces">
                    <a href="#">CENTRO DE AYUDA</a>
                   </div>
                </nav>
            </div> <!--.nav-->

        </div>
    </header>

    <main class="contenedor2 centrador-texto">
        <div class="c-principal">

            <div class="c-izquierda">
                <p class="c-izquierda__titulos">Mensajería confiable,</p>
                <p class="c-izquierda__titulos">Simple,</p>
                <p class="c-izquierda__titulos">Segura</p>

                <p class="c-izquierda__contenido">
                    Con WhatsApp, la mensajería y las llamadas son rápidas, simples, seguras y gratuitas*, disponibles en teléfonos alrededor del mundo.
                </p>
                <p class="c-izquierda__gris">
                    * Puede haber cargos adicionales por el uso del servicio de datos. Contacta a tu operador de telefonía móvil para más información.
                </p>

                <ul class="dispositivos">
                    <li class="dispositivos__wsp">
                        <a href="#" class="dispositivos__enlaces">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px"
                                width="24" height="24"
                                viewBox="0 0 172 172"
                                style=" fill:#000000;"><g fill="none" fill-rule="nonzero" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="" stroke-dashoffset="0" font-family="none" font-weight="none" font-size="none" text-anchor="none" style="mix-blend-mode: normal"><path d="M0,172v-172h172v172z" fill="none"></path><g id="original-icon" fill="#128c7e"><path d="M53.75,7.16667c-0.91733,0 -1.83478,0.35105 -2.53353,1.0498c-1.3975,1.3975 -1.3975,3.66956 0,5.06706l9.39225,9.39225c-10.66343,7.82497 -17.60872,20.41563 -17.60872,34.65755h86c0,-14.24192 -6.9453,-26.83258 -17.60872,-34.65755l9.39225,-9.39225c1.3975,-1.40467 1.3975,-3.66239 0,-5.06706c-1.3975,-1.3975 -3.66956,-1.3975 -5.06706,0l-10.62402,10.62402c-5.75803,-2.86198 -12.22542,-4.50716 -19.09244,-4.50716c-6.86703,0 -13.33441,1.64518 -19.09245,4.50716l-10.62402,-10.62402c-0.69875,-0.69875 -1.6162,-1.0498 -2.53353,-1.0498zM64.5,35.83333h7.16667v7.16667h-7.16667zM100.33333,35.83333h7.16667v7.16667h-7.16667zM28.66667,64.5c-3.956,0 -7.16667,3.21067 -7.16667,7.16667v43c0,3.956 3.21067,7.16667 7.16667,7.16667c3.956,0 7.16667,-3.21067 7.16667,-7.16667v-43c0,-3.956 -3.21067,-7.16667 -7.16667,-7.16667zM43,64.5v57.33333c0,3.956 3.21067,7.16667 7.16667,7.16667h7.16667v25.08333c0,5.934 4.816,10.75 10.75,10.75c5.934,0 10.75,-4.816 10.75,-10.75v-25.08333h14.33333v25.08333c0,5.934 4.816,10.75 10.75,10.75c5.934,0 10.75,-4.816 10.75,-10.75v-25.08333h7.16667c3.956,0 7.16667,-3.21067 7.16667,-7.16667v-57.33333zM143.33333,64.5c-3.956,0 -7.16667,3.21067 -7.16667,7.16667v43c0,3.956 3.21067,7.16667 7.16667,7.16667c3.956,0 7.16667,-3.21067 7.16667,-7.16667v-43c0,-3.956 -3.21067,-7.16667 -7.16667,-7.16667z"></path></g></g>
                            </svg>
                            <span class="dispositivos__nombre">Android</span>
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px"
                                width="30" height="30"
                                viewBox="0 0 172 172"
                                style=" fill:#000000;"><g fill="none" fill-rule="nonzero" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="" stroke-dashoffset="0" font-family="none" font-weight="none" font-size="none" text-anchor="none" style="mix-blend-mode: normal"><path d="M0,172v-172h172v172z" fill="none"></path><g fill="#128c7e"><path d="M68.8,154.8h-11.46667c-2.21307,0 -4.2312,-1.27853 -5.18293,-3.27947c-0.95173,-2.00093 -0.65933,-4.3688 0.74533,-6.0888l48.63013,-59.43173l-48.63013,-59.43747c-1.40467,-1.71427 -1.69133,-4.08213 -0.74533,-6.0888c0.946,-2.00667 2.96987,-3.27373 5.18293,-3.27373h11.46667c1.72,0 3.34827,0.774 4.4376,2.10413l51.6,63.06667c1.72573,2.1156 1.72573,5.14853 0,7.26413l-51.6,63.06667c-1.08933,1.3244 -2.7176,2.0984 -4.4376,2.0984z"></path></g></g>
                            </svg>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="dispositivos__enlaces">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px"
                            width="24" height="24"
                            viewBox="0 0 172 172"
                            style=" fill:#000000;"><g fill="none" fill-rule="nonzero" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="" stroke-dashoffset="0" font-family="none" font-weight="none" font-size="none" text-anchor="none" style="mix-blend-mode: normal"><path d="M0,172v-172h172v172z" fill="none"></path><g fill="#128c7e"><path d="M113.9808,7.72656c-0.43672,-0.06719 -0.93223,-0.0252 -1.46973,0.15397c-7.16667,1.43333 -15.0416,5.73333 -20.05827,10.75c-4.3,4.3 -7.88054,11.46667 -7.88054,17.91667c0,1.43333 1.42214,2.86947 2.85547,2.86947c7.88333,-0.71667 15.76946,-5.01947 20.78613,-10.03613c4.3,-5.73333 7.88054,-12.18053 7.88054,-18.63053c0,-1.6125 -0.80345,-2.82188 -2.11361,-3.02344zM116.0944,38.7028c-12.9,0 -18.62493,7.88053 -27.22493,7.88053c-9.31667,0 -17.91667,-7.16667 -28.66667,-7.16667c-15.05,0 -37.98893,14.33053 -37.98893,47.2972c-0.71667,30.1 26.51947,63.78614 42.28613,63.78614c9.31667,0 11.46947,-5.73893 24.36947,-5.73893c12.9,0 15.76667,5.73893 25.08333,5.73893c10.75,0 18.63333,-11.46947 25.08333,-20.78614c2.86667,-5.01667 5.01667,-7.87773 7.16667,-12.17773c1.43333,-2.86667 -0.0028,-5.73333 -2.86947,-7.16667c-18.63333,-9.31667 -22.21107,-39.41667 -1.42774,-50.16667c3.58333,-2.15 4.2944,-6.4584 1.42774,-8.6084c-7.88333,-7.16667 -19.3556,-12.8916 -27.23893,-12.8916z"></path></g></g>
                            </svg>
                            <span class="dispositivos__nombre">iPhone</span>
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px"
                                width="30" height="30"
                                viewBox="0 0 172 172"
                                style=" fill:#000000;"><g fill="none" fill-rule="nonzero" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="" stroke-dashoffset="0" font-family="none" font-weight="none" font-size="none" text-anchor="none" style="mix-blend-mode: normal"><path d="M0,172v-172h172v172z" fill="none"></path><g fill="#128c7e"><path d="M68.8,154.8h-11.46667c-2.21307,0 -4.2312,-1.27853 -5.18293,-3.27947c-0.95173,-2.00093 -0.65933,-4.3688 0.74533,-6.0888l48.63013,-59.43173l-48.63013,-59.43747c-1.40467,-1.71427 -1.69133,-4.08213 -0.74533,-6.0888c0.946,-2.00667 2.96987,-3.27373 5.18293,-3.27373h11.46667c1.72,0 3.34827,0.774 4.4376,2.10413l51.6,63.06667c1.72573,2.1156 1.72573,5.14853 0,7.26413l-51.6,63.06667c-1.08933,1.3244 -2.7176,2.0984 -4.4376,2.0984z"></path></g></g>
                            </svg>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="dispositivos__enlaces">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px"
                            width="30" height="30"
                            viewBox="0 0 172 172"
                            style=" fill:#000000;"><g fill="none" fill-rule="nonzero" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="" stroke-dashoffset="0" font-family="none" font-weight="none" font-size="none" text-anchor="none" style="mix-blend-mode: normal"><path d="M0,172v-172h172v172z" fill="none"></path><g fill="#128c7e"><path d="M158.93947,131.86667c0.98613,-1.69133 1.59387,-3.63493 1.59387,-5.73333v-86c0,-6.32387 -5.1428,-11.46667 -11.46667,-11.46667h-126.13333c-6.32387,0 -11.46667,5.1428 -11.46667,11.46667v86c0,2.0984 0.60773,4.042 1.59387,5.73333h-13.06053v5.73333c0,6.33533 5.13133,11.46667 11.46667,11.46667h149.06667c6.33533,0 11.46667,-5.13133 11.46667,-11.46667v-5.73333zM103.2,126.13333c0,3.1648 -2.56853,5.73333 -5.73333,5.73333h-17.2c-3.1648,0 -5.73333,-2.56853 -5.73333,-5.73333h-51.6v-86h126.13333l0.00573,86z"></path></g></g>
                            </svg>
                                <span class="dispositivos__nombre">Mac o Windows</span>
                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px"
                                width="30" height="30"
                                viewBox="0 0 172 172"
                                style=" fill:#000000;"><g fill="none" fill-rule="nonzero" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="" stroke-dashoffset="0" font-family="none" font-weight="none" font-size="none" text-anchor="none" style="mix-blend-mode: normal"><path d="M0,172v-172h172v172z" fill="none"></path><g fill="#128c7e"><path d="M68.8,154.8h-11.46667c-2.21307,0 -4.2312,-1.27853 -5.18293,-3.27947c-0.95173,-2.00093 -0.65933,-4.3688 0.74533,-6.0888l48.63013,-59.43173l-48.63013,-59.43747c-1.40467,-1.71427 -1.69133,-4.08213 -0.74533,-6.0888c0.946,-2.00667 2.96987,-3.27373 5.18293,-3.27373h11.46667c1.72,0 3.34827,0.774 4.4376,2.10413l51.6,63.06667c1.72573,2.1156 1.72573,5.14853 0,7.26413l-51.6,63.06667c-1.08933,1.3244 -2.7176,2.0984 -4.4376,2.0984z"></path></g></g>
                            </svg>

                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </div>


            <div class="c-derecha">
                <img src="img/celular.png" alt="Imagen derecha">
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </main>

    <section class="c-secundario centrador-texto">
        <div class="s-izquierda">
            <h2 class="s-izquierda__titulo">Aplicación WhatsApp Business</h2>
            <p class="s-izquierda__contenido">
                <a class="s-izquierda__enlace" href="#">WhatsApp Business</a> es una aplicación de descarga gratuita desarrollada especialmente para pequeñas empresas. Crea un catálogo para mostrar tus productos y servicios. Conéctate fácilmente con tus clientes gracias a las herramientas que te permiten automatizar, organizar y responder con rapidez los mensajes.
            </p>

            <p class="s-izquierda__contenido">WhatsApp también puede ser útil para las empresas medianas y grandes, ya que pueden usarlo para brindar asistencia y enviar notificaciones importantes a sus clientes. Obtén más información sobre la API de WhatsApp Business.
            </p>

            <img src="img/celular2.png" alt="Imagen de la seccion secundaria<">
                

        </div>
        <div class="s-derecha">
            <img src="img/celular3.PNG" alt="Imagen de la seccion secundaria (2)">
            <p class="s-derecha__encabezado">
                CIFRADO DE EXTREMO A EXTREMO
            </p>
            <h2 class="s-derecha__titulo">Seguridad automática</h2>
            <p class="s-derecha__contenido">
                Algunos de tus momentos más personales se comparten a través de WhatsApp; es por ello que desarrollamos el cifrado de extremo a extremo en las versiones más recientes de nuestra aplicación. Con el cifrado de extremo a extremo, tus mensajes y llamadas están protegidos para que solo las personas con las que te comunicas los puedan leer o escuchar sin que nadie más, ni siquiera WhatsApp, lo pueda hacer.
            </p>
            
        </div>
    </section>

    <div class="boton centrador-texto">
        <a href="#" class="boton-ex">Explorar Funciones</a>
    </div>

    <section class="menu-abajo">
        <div class="fondo-menu">
            <div class="c-menu contenedor">
                <div class="menus">
                    <p>WhatsApp</p>
                    <a href="#" class="menus__enlaces">Funciones</a>
                    <a href="#" class="menus__enlaces">Seguridad</a>
                    <a href="#" class="menus__enlaces">Descargar</a>
                    <a href="#" class="menus__enlaces">WhatsApp Web</a>
                    <a href="#" class="menus__enlaces">Empresas</a>
                    <a href="#" class="menus__enlaces">Privacidad</a>
                </div>
                <div class="menus">
                    <p>Empresa</p>
                    <a href="#" class="menus__enlaces">Información</a>
                    <a href="#" class="menus__enlaces">Empleo</a>
                    <a href="#" class="menus__enlaces">Nuestra marca</a>
                    <a href="#" class="menus__enlaces">Contáctanos</a>
                    <a href="#" class="menus__enlaces">Blog</a>
                    <a href="#" class="menus__enlaces">Historias de WhatsApp</a>
                </div>
                
                <div class="menus">
                    <p>Descargar</p>
                    <a href="#" class="menus__enlaces">Mac/PC</a>
                    <a href="#" class="menus__enlaces">Android</a>
                    <a href="#" class="menus__enlaces">iPhone</a>
                </div>
                <div class="menus">
                    <p>Ayuda</p>
                    <a href="#" class="menus__enlaces">Centro de ayuda</a>
                    <a href="#" class="menus__enlaces">Twitter</a>
                    <a href="#" class="menus__enlaces">Facebook</a>
                    <a href="#" class="menus__enlaces">Coronavirus</a>
                    <a href="#" class="menus__enlaces">Empresas</a>
                    <a href="#" class="menus__enlaces">Privacidad</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    

    
</body>
</html>
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Answer (score 0):

En responsive design es comun este tipo de stacking de elementos. Usualmente para lograr esto se hace uso de `display:flex` y una combinación entre `flex-direction: row` y `flex-direction: column`.

Para tu caso en particular en el cual necesitas hacer stack del `barra-nav` puedes hacer uso de esta estrategia en la siguiente forma.

**ten en cuenta que `align-items: center;` nos ayudara a evitar que los `<a>` internos se extiendan por toda la pantalla y asi solo ocupen solo su espacio**

```css
 .barra-nav {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
 }
 @media (min-width: 769px) {
     .barra-nav {
         align-items: unset;
         flex-direction: row;
     }
 }
```

El código funcionando lo puedes probar aqui:

```css
:root{
    --colorBarra: #128c7e;
    --colorA1: #D8E8EA;
    --colorA2: #E7F0E4;
    --negro: #000000;
    --blanco: #ffffff;
    --gris: #5E5E5E;
    --boton : #77d7c8;

    --fuenteBarra: 'Roboto', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;

}

html{
    box-sizing: border-box; /** Para hacer que el border, el padding, etc, no afecte el ancho de nuestros elementos**/
    font-size: 62.5%; /** Para que 1rem = 10px**/ 
}

*, *:before, *:after{
    box-sizing: inherit;

}

body{
    font-family: var(--fuenteBarra);
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    line-height: 2.3rem;
}

img{
    max-width: 100%;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

.contenedor{
    max-width: 120rem;
    width: 85%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.contenedor2{
    max-width: 120rem;
    width: 65%;
    margin: 0 auto;

}

.centrador-texto{
    text-align: center;
}

/** Barra Navegacion**/


.background-nav{
    background-color: var(--colorBarra);
}

.logo-imagen__texto{
    color: var(--blanco);
    font-family: var(--fuenteBarra);
    font-size: 2.4rem;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.barra-nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
.barra-nav__enlaces{
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 2.5rem;
    color: var(--blanco);
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    font-family: var(--fuenteBarra);
}

.barra-nav__enlaces:first-of-type{
    margin-top: 2rem;
}

@media (min-width: 769px) {
    .nav{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        padding: .5rem 0;
    }
    .barra-nav__enlaces{
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    .logo-imagen{
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .logo-imagen__texto{
        margin-left: 1rem;
    }

    .barra-nav {
       align-items: unset;
       flex-direction: row;
    }

    .barra-nav__enlaces{
        margin-right: 3rem;
    }
    .barra-nav__enlaces:last-of-type{
        margin-right: 0;
    }
    .barra-nav__enlaces:first-of-type{
        margin-top: 0;
    }

}

/** Contenido debajo del nav**/
.c-principal{
    margin-top: 5rem;
    margin-bottom: 5rem;
}

.c-izquierda__titulos{
    font-size: 3.5rem;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 1rem;

}

.c-izquierda__titulos:first-of-type{
    line-height: 4rem;
}

.c-izquierda__contenido{
    text-align: left;

}

.c-izquierda__gris{
    text-align: left;
    color: var(--gris);
    margin-bottom: 4rem;

}

.dispositivos{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}

.dispositivos__enlaces{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding-bottom: 2rem;
}

.dispositivos__nombre{
    padding: 0 .3rem;
    color: var(--colorBarra);
}

.dispositivos__nombre:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
}

@media (min-width: 769px) {
    .c-principal{
        display: grid;  
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
        column-gap: 5rem;
    }
    
    .c-izquierda{
        padding: 10rem 0;
    }
}

/** Seccion Secundaria **/

.s-izquierda{
    background-color: var(--colorA1);
    padding: 5rem;
}

.s-izquierda__contenido,
.s-derecha__contenido{
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    line-height: 2.6rem;
}

.s-izquierda__titulo,
.s-derecha__titulo{
    font-size: 3rem;
    line-height: 4rem;
}

.s-izquierda__contenido:last-of-type{
    margin-bottom: 7rem;
}

.s-derecha{
    background-color: var(--colorA2);
    padding: 5rem;
}

.s-derecha__encabezado{
    color: #5E5E5E;
    letter-spacing: .2rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 1.8rem;
}

.s-izquierda img{
    max-width: 80%;
}

.s-izquierda__enlace{
    color: #39b3ed;
}

.s-derecha img{
    margin-bottom: 7rem;
}

@media (min-width: 769px) {
    .c-secundario{
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
        column-gap: 5rem;
    }
    
}

/** Boton **/
.boton{
    margin: 4rem;
}

.boton .boton-ex{
    border: 2px solid var(--boton);
    border-radius: 50rem;
    padding: 1.5rem 4rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: var(--colorBarra);
}

/** Menu de abajo**/

.fondo-menu{
    background-color: #273443;
    padding: 2.5rem 0;
}

.menus p{
    color: var(--blanco);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: .2rem;
}

.menus{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>WhatsApp</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="background-nav">
            <div class="nav contenedor centrador-texto">

                <a href="#" class="logo-imagen">
                    <img src="img/wsp_logo.png" alt="Imagen logo" class="logo-imagen__logo">
                    <p class="logo-imagen__texto">WhatsApp</p>
                </a>

                <nav class="barra-nav">
                    <a href="#" class="barra-nav__enlaces">WHATSAPP WEB</a>
                    <a href="#" class="barra-nav__enlaces">FUNCIONES</a>
                    <a href="#" class="barra-nav__enlaces">DESCARGAR</a>
                    <a href="#" class="barra-nav__enlaces">SEGURIDAD</a>
                    <a href="#" class="barra-nav__enlaces">CENTRO DE AYUDA</a>
                </nav>
            </div> <!--.nav-->

        </div>
    </header>

    <main class="contenedor2 centrador-texto">
        <div class="c-principal">

            <div class="c-izquierda">
                <p class="c-izquierda__titulos">Mensajería confiable,</p>
                <p class="c-izquierda__titulos">Simple,</p>
                <p class="c-izquierda__titulos">Segura</p>

                <p class="c-izquierda__contenido">
                    Con WhatsApp, la mensajería y las llamadas son rápidas, simples, seguras y gratuitas*, disponibles en teléfonos alrededor del mundo.
                </p>
                <p class="c-izquierda__gris">
                    * Puede haber cargos adicionales por el uso del servicio de datos. Contacta a tu operador de telefonía móvil para más información.
                </p>

                <ul class="dispositivos">
                    <li class="dispositivos__wsp">
                        <a href="#" class="dispositivos__enlaces">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px"
                                width="24" height="24"
                                viewBox="0 0 172 172"
                                style=" fill:#000000;"><g fill="none" fill-rule="nonzero" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="" stroke-dashoffset="0" font-family="none" font-weight="none" font-size="none" text-anchor="none" style="mix-blend-mode: normal"><path d="M0,172v-172h172v172z" fill="none"></path><g id="original-icon" fill="#128c7e"><path d="M53.75,7.16667c-0.91733,0 -1.83478,0.35105 -2.53353,1.0498c-1.3975,1.3975 -1.3975,3.66956 0,5.06706l9.39225,9.39225c-10.66343,7.82497 -17.60872,20.41563 -17.60872,34.65755h86c0,-14.24192 -6.9453,-26.83258 -17.60872,-34.65755l9.39225,-9.39225c1.3975,-1.40467 1.3975,-3.66239 0,-5.06706c-1.3975,-1.3975 -3.66956,-1.3975 -5.06706,0l-10.62402,10.62402c-5.75803,-2.86198 -12.22542,-4.50716 -19.09244,-4.50716c-6.86703,0 -13.33441,1.64518 -19.09245,4.50716l-10.62402,-10.62402c-0.69875,-0.69875 -1.6162,-1.0498 -2.53353,-1.0498zM64.5,35.83333h7.16667v7.16667h-7.16667zM100.33333,35.83333h7.16667v7.16667h-7.16667zM28.66667,64.5c-3.956,0 -7.16667,3.21067 -7.16667,7.16667v43c0,3.956 3.21067,7.16667 7.16667,7.16667c3.956,0 7.16667,-3.21067 7.16667,-7.16667v-43c0,-3.956 -3.21067,-7.16667 -7.16667,-7.16667zM43,64.5v57.33333c0,3.956 3.21067,7.16667 7.16667,7.16667h7.16667v25.08333c0,5.934 4.816,10.75 10.75,10.75c5.934,0 10.75,-4.816 10.75,-10.75v-25.08333h14.33333v25.08333c0,5.934 4.816,10.75 10.75,10.75c5.934,0 10.75,-4.816 10.75,-10.75v-25.08333h7.16667c3.956,0 7.16667,-3.21067 7.16667,-7.16667v-57.33333zM143.33333,64.5c-3.956,0 -7.16667,3.21067 -7.16667,7.16667v43c0,3.956 3.21067,7.16667 7.16667,7.16667c3.956,0 7.16667,-3.21067 7.16667,-7.16667v-43c0,-3.956 -3.21067,-7.16667 -7.16667,-7.16667z"></path></g></g>
                            </svg>
                            <span class="dispositivos__nombre">Android</span>
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px"
                                width="30" height="30"
                                viewBox="0 0 172 172"
                                style=" fill:#000000;"><g fill="none" fill-rule="nonzero" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="" stroke-dashoffset="0" font-family="none" font-weight="none" font-size="none" text-anchor="none" style="mix-blend-mode: normal"><path d="M0,172v-172h172v172z" fill="none"></path><g fill="#128c7e"><path d="M68.8,154.8h-11.46667c-2.21307,0 -4.2312,-1.27853 -5.18293,-3.27947c-0.95173,-2.00093 -0.65933,-4.3688 0.74533,-6.0888l48.63013,-59.43173l-48.63013,-59.43747c-1.40467,-1.71427 -1.69133,-4.08213 -0.74533,-6.0888c0.946,-2.00667 2.96987,-3.27373 5.18293,-3.27373h11.46667c1.72,0 3.34827,0.774 4.4376,2.10413l51.6,63.06667c1.72573,2.1156 1.72573,5.14853 0,7.26413l-51.6,63.06667c-1.08933,1.3244 -2.7176,2.0984 -4.4376,2.0984z"></path></g></g>
                            </svg>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="dispositivos__enlaces">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px"
                            width="24" height="24"
                            viewBox="0 0 172 172"
                            style=" fill:#000000;"><g fill="none" fill-rule="nonzero" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="" stroke-dashoffset="0" font-family="none" font-weight="none" font-size="none" text-anchor="none" style="mix-blend-mode: normal"><path d="M0,172v-172h172v172z" fill="none"></path><g fill="#128c7e"><path d="M113.9808,7.72656c-0.43672,-0.06719 -0.93223,-0.0252 -1.46973,0.15397c-7.16667,1.43333 -15.0416,5.73333 -20.05827,10.75c-4.3,4.3 -7.88054,11.46667 -7.88054,17.91667c0,1.43333 1.42214,2.86947 2.85547,2.86947c7.88333,-0.71667 15.76946,-5.01947 20.78613,-10.03613c4.3,-5.73333 7.88054,-12.18053 7.88054,-18.63053c0,-1.6125 -0.80345,-2.82188 -2.11361,-3.02344zM116.0944,38.7028c-12.9,0 -18.62493,7.88053 -27.22493,7.88053c-9.31667,0 -17.91667,-7.16667 -28.66667,-7.16667c-15.05,0 -37.98893,14.33053 -37.98893,47.2972c-0.71667,30.1 26.51947,63.78614 42.28613,63.78614c9.31667,0 11.46947,-5.73893 24.36947,-5.73893c12.9,0 15.76667,5.73893 25.08333,5.73893c10.75,0 18.63333,-11.46947 25.08333,-20.78614c2.86667,-5.01667 5.01667,-7.87773 7.16667,-12.17773c1.43333,-2.86667 -0.0028,-5.73333 -2.86947,-7.16667c-18.63333,-9.31667 -22.21107,-39.41667 -1.42774,-50.16667c3.58333,-2.15 4.2944,-6.4584 1.42774,-8.6084c-7.88333,-7.16667 -19.3556,-12.8916 -27.23893,-12.8916z"></path></g></g>
                            </svg>
                            <span class="dispositivos__nombre">iPhone</span>
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px"
                                width="30" height="30"
                                viewBox="0 0 172 172"
                                style=" fill:#000000;"><g fill="none" fill-rule="nonzero" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="" stroke-dashoffset="0" font-family="none" font-weight="none" font-size="none" text-anchor="none" style="mix-blend-mode: normal"><path d="M0,172v-172h172v172z" fill="none"></path><g fill="#128c7e"><path d="M68.8,154.8h-11.46667c-2.21307,0 -4.2312,-1.27853 -5.18293,-3.27947c-0.95173,-2.00093 -0.65933,-4.3688 0.74533,-6.0888l48.63013,-59.43173l-48.63013,-59.43747c-1.40467,-1.71427 -1.69133,-4.08213 -0.74533,-6.0888c0.946,-2.00667 2.96987,-3.27373 5.18293,-3.27373h11.46667c1.72,0 3.34827,0.774 4.4376,2.10413l51.6,63.06667c1.72573,2.1156 1.72573,5.14853 0,7.26413l-51.6,63.06667c-1.08933,1.3244 -2.7176,2.0984 -4.4376,2.0984z"></path></g></g>
                            </svg>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="dispositivos__enlaces">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px"
                            width="30" height="30"
                            viewBox="0 0 172 172"
                            style=" fill:#000000;"><g fill="none" fill-rule="nonzero" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="" stroke-dashoffset="0" font-family="none" font-weight="none" font-size="none" text-anchor="none" style="mix-blend-mode: normal"><path d="M0,172v-172h172v172z" fill="none"></path><g fill="#128c7e"><path d="M158.93947,131.86667c0.98613,-1.69133 1.59387,-3.63493 1.59387,-5.73333v-86c0,-6.32387 -5.1428,-11.46667 -11.46667,-11.46667h-126.13333c-6.32387,0 -11.46667,5.1428 -11.46667,11.46667v86c0,2.0984 0.60773,4.042 1.59387,5.73333h-13.06053v5.73333c0,6.33533 5.13133,11.46667 11.46667,11.46667h149.06667c6.33533,0 11.46667,-5.13133 11.46667,-11.46667v-5.73333zM103.2,126.13333c0,3.1648 -2.56853,5.73333 -5.73333,5.73333h-17.2c-3.1648,0 -5.73333,-2.56853 -5.73333,-5.73333h-51.6v-86h126.13333l0.00573,86z"></path></g></g>
                            </svg>
                                <span class="dispositivos__nombre">Mac o Windows</span>
                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px"
                                width="30" height="30"
                                viewBox="0 0 172 172"
                                style=" fill:#000000;"><g fill="none" fill-rule="nonzero" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="" stroke-dashoffset="0" font-family="none" font-weight="none" font-size="none" text-anchor="none" style="mix-blend-mode: normal"><path d="M0,172v-172h172v172z" fill="none"></path><g fill="#128c7e"><path d="M68.8,154.8h-11.46667c-2.21307,0 -4.2312,-1.27853 -5.18293,-3.27947c-0.95173,-2.00093 -0.65933,-4.3688 0.74533,-6.0888l48.63013,-59.43173l-48.63013,-59.43747c-1.40467,-1.71427 -1.69133,-4.08213 -0.74533,-6.0888c0.946,-2.00667 2.96987,-3.27373 5.18293,-3.27373h11.46667c1.72,0 3.34827,0.774 4.4376,2.10413l51.6,63.06667c1.72573,2.1156 1.72573,5.14853 0,7.26413l-51.6,63.06667c-1.08933,1.3244 -2.7176,2.0984 -4.4376,2.0984z"></path></g></g>
                            </svg>

                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </div>


            <div class="c-derecha">
                <img src="img/celular.png" alt="Imagen derecha">
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </main>

    <section class="c-secundario centrador-texto">
        <div class="s-izquierda">
            <h2 class="s-izquierda__titulo">Aplicación WhatsApp Business</h2>
            <p class="s-izquierda__contenido">
                <a class="s-izquierda__enlace" href="#">WhatsApp Business</a> es una aplicación de descarga gratuita desarrollada especialmente para pequeñas empresas. Crea un catálogo para mostrar tus productos y servicios. Conéctate fácilmente con tus clientes gracias a las herramientas que te permiten automatizar, organizar y responder con rapidez los mensajes.
            </p>

            <p class="s-izquierda__contenido">WhatsApp también puede ser útil para las empresas medianas y grandes, ya que pueden usarlo para brindar asistencia y enviar notificaciones importantes a sus clientes. Obtén más información sobre la API de WhatsApp Business.
            </p>

            <img src="img/celular2.png" alt="Imagen de la seccion secundaria<">
                

        </div>
        <div class="s-derecha">
            <img src="img/celular3.PNG" alt="Imagen de la seccion secundaria (2)">
            <p class="s-derecha__encabezado">
                CIFRADO DE EXTREMO A EXTREMO
            </p>
            <h2 class="s-derecha__titulo">Seguridad automática</h2>
            <p class="s-derecha__contenido">
                Algunos de tus momentos más personales se comparten a través de WhatsApp; es por ello que desarrollamos el cifrado de extremo a extremo en las versiones más recientes de nuestra aplicación. Con el cifrado de extremo a extremo, tus mensajes y llamadas están protegidos para que solo las personas con las que te comunicas los puedan leer o escuchar sin que nadie más, ni siquiera WhatsApp, lo pueda hacer.
            </p>
            
        </div>
    </section>

    <div class="boton centrador-texto">
        <a href="#" class="boton-ex">Explorar Funciones</a>
    </div>

    <section class="menu-abajo">
        <div class="fondo-menu">
            <div class="c-menu contenedor">
                <div class="menus">
                    <p>WhatsApp</p>
                    <a href="#" class="menus__enlaces">Funciones</a>
                    <a href="#" class="menus__enlaces">Seguridad</a>
                    <a href="#" class="menus__enlaces">Descargar</a>
                    <a href="#" class="menus__enlaces">WhatsApp Web</a>
                    <a href="#" class="menus__enlaces">Empresas</a>
                    <a href="#" class="menus__enlaces">Privacidad</a>
                </div>
                <div class="menus">
                    <p>Empresa</p>
                    <a href="#" class="menus__enlaces">Información</a>
                    <a href="#" class="menus__enlaces">Empleo</a>
                    <a href="#" class="menus__enlaces">Nuestra marca</a>
                    <a href="#" class="menus__enlaces">Contáctanos</a>
                    <a href="#" class="menus__enlaces">Blog</a>
                    <a href="#" class="menus__enlaces">Historias de WhatsApp</a>
                </div>
                
                <div class="menus">
                    <p>Descargar</p>
                    <a href="#" class="menus__enlaces">Mac/PC</a>
                    <a href="#" class="menus__enlaces">Android</a>
                    <a href="#" class="menus__enlaces">iPhone</a>
                </div>
                <div class="menus">
                    <p>Ayuda</p>
                    <a href="#" class="menus__enlaces">Centro de ayuda</a>
                    <a href="#" class="menus__enlaces">Twitter</a>
                    <a href="#" class="menus__enlaces">Facebook</a>
                    <a href="#" class="menus__enlaces">Coronavirus</a>
                    <a href="#" class="menus__enlaces">Empresas</a>
                    <a href="#" class="menus__enlaces">Privacidad</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    

    
</body>
</html>
```